# Gem I wrote not executable on linux, but seems to work on windows

Tags: linux, rubygems

I wrote a gem called "getDartPortalAndInitBuild" on windows to grab some dependencies from our artifactory. When I do a rake install, the gem works beautifully on windows. I upload it to our gem repository using geminabox, which works fine.

I then install it on our linux box as root

```
gem install getDartPortalAndInitBuild
```

The install seems to work correctly. When I type getDartPortalAndInitBuild, it says "Command not found." I found where the gem was installed, and noticed the bin folder (the folder containing the executable) was missing. I made one, and also created the executable again. I chmodded the file, and tried to execute it. Same issue. I checked my /usr/bin folder, and getDartPortalAndInitBuild wasn't there. I tried to do a rake install on the gem but, it still did not add the executable. Finally, I grew frustrated, and copied the executable into the bin. That did execute the file, but I got `require': no such file to load -- getDartPortalAndInitBuild.

This is my gem environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:

  - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - /root/.gem/ruby/1.8
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :benchmark => false
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000

This is my $PATH

```
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8:/root/.gem/ruby/1.8:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin:/root/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/usr/bin/ruby
```

This is the full gemspec

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'getDartPortalAndInitBuild/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "getDartPortalAndInitBuild"
  spec.version       = GetDartPortalAndInitBuild::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["Tyler MacMillan"]
  spec.email         = ["tyler.macmillan@recondotech.com"]
  spec.description   = "Gets risvc, dartsvc, entrypoint, rcp, dataadmin, and user management and initializes the install script"
  spec.summary       = "Grab wars and build portal for iAT server"
  spec.homepage      = ""
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.lines.map { |s| s.chomp }
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.3"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
end
```

This is the relevant part of my executable (with name getDartPortalAndInitBuild):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'getDartPortalAndInitBuild'
```

How do I get my gem to install itself correctly? My path seems to be correct, and again, everything works well on windows. Thank you in advance for your help, and please ask if I haven't supplied enough information.

UPDATE:

It is worth noting that unless I do a rake install, the executable does not work on windows, either.

Comment: Sounds like the gem was built on Windows? You could try replacing the spec.files line with `git ls-files`.lines.map { |s| s.chomp } and rebuilding the gem. I think $/ is "\n" by default, perhaps you're getting a stray carriage return at the end of the file names.

Comment: I'm afraid that did not work (everything compiles, it just does not solve my problem). An interesting idea, though.

Comment: Is your gem on GitHub or could you produce a minimal version that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: @RichardCook It is not on GitHub. What would qualify as a minimal version, since the code itself isn't the problem? I'm happy to supply the full gemspec if that will work?

Comment: @TylerMacMillan: The full gemspec might help.

Comment: @RichardCook - Full gemspec added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced

```
spec.executables = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
```

with

```
spec.executables = ["getDartPortalAndInitBuild"]
```

And now it functions. I am not sure why the rake install worked correctly, but there it is.